# How to split data with pandas and compute the sum of the splited data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that is organized like this:

```
Timestamp  slot_ID   counter1  Counter2
1552227371    1        0         1
1552227372    2        1         0
1552227373    3        1         1
...         ...       ..       ...
1552229621    100      1         1
1552229622    1        1         0
1552229623    2        0         1
1552229624    3        1         1
...         ...       ..       ...
1552229626    100      1         1
```

I want to split my data frame  based on slot_ID than compute the sum of different Counter for the 100 slot_ID.  The counter 1 and the counter 2 have the value 0 or 1 all the time.  That means the sum of every 100 slots is less or equal to 100.

```
def consecutive_groups(iterable, ordering=lambda x: x):
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x: x==100):
        yield map(itemgetter(1), g)

   grpsper100 = consecutive_groups(df_node['slot_ID'].index)
dfs = {i: df.iloc[list(j)] for i, j in enumerate(grpsper100, 1)}
for key, value in dfs.items():
    #print(value['slot_ID'])
    print(key)
    print(value['Counter1'].sum())
    print(value['Counter2'].sum())
```

However my code does not give me the expected answer:

```
   key: 1
   Counter1: 119083
   Counter2:  117400
```

How to correct my code please?

Comment: What you need is `dfs.loc[dfs['slot_ID'] == 100, dfs['counter1']].sum()` and `dfs.loc[dfs['slot_ID'] == 100, dfs['counter2']].sum()`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander  thank you for your answer, but it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you had a dict by that name, and that your dataframe is called `df`. So then it's `df.loc[df['slot_ID'] == 100, df['counter1']].sum()`

Comment: Thank you for your help but it gives me a memory error.